# Why are the CPU Physical Address Space and Bus Address Space different?

Tags: bus, address-space

I'm reading about DMA and it refers to the following address spaces:

- CPU Virtual Address Space
- CPU Physical Address Space
- Bus Address Space

I understand why the virtual and physical address space is different... by why is there a mapping required between the physical and bus address spaces? What would cause these to be different?